# How can C++ object lifetimes be correctly managed in Cython?

Tags: c++, python, memory, cython

When writing a Cython wrapper for a C++ library, I've encountered a case where it's not clear how to correctly decide when to delete certain C++ instances.

The C++ library looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class Widget {
    char *name;
    public:
        Widget() : name(strdup("a widget")) {}
        ~Widget() { printf("Widget destruct\n"); }
        void foo() { printf("Widget::foo %s\n", this->name); }
};

class Sprocket {
    private:
        Widget *important;

    public:
        Sprocket(Widget* important) : important(important) {}
        ~Sprocket() { important->foo(); }
};
```

An important aspect of this library is that the `Sprocket` destructor uses the `Widget*` it was given, so the `Widget` must not be destroyed until after the `Sprocket` has been.

The Cython wrapper I've written looks like this:

```
cdef extern from "somelib.h":
    cdef cppclass Widget:
        pass

    cdef cppclass Sprocket:
        Sprocket(Widget*)


cdef class PyWidget:
    cdef Widget *thisptr

    def __init__(self):
        self.thisptr = new Widget()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        print 'PyWidget dealloc'
        del self.thisptr


cdef class PySprocket:
    cdef PyWidget widget
    cdef Sprocket *thisptr

    def __init__(self, PyWidget widget):
        self.widget = widget
        self.thisptr = new Sprocket(self.widget.thisptr)


    def __dealloc__(self):
        print 'PySprocket dealloc with widget', self.widget
        del self.thisptr
```

After building the Python build like this:

```
$ cython --cplus somelib.pyx 
$ g++ -I/usr/include/python2.6 -L/usr/lib somelib.cpp -shared -o somelib.so
$
```

In the trivial case, it appears to work:

```
$ python -c 'from somelib import PyWidget, PySprocket
spr = PySprocket(PyWidget())
del spr
'
PySprocket dealloc with widget <somelib.PyWidget object at 0xb7537080>
Widget::foo a widget
PyWidget dealloc
Widget destruct
$
```

The `cdef Widget` field keeps the `PyWidget` alive until after `PySprocket.__dealloc__` destroys the `Sprocket`.  However, as soon as the Python garbage collected gets involved, the `tp_clear` function Cython constructs for `PySprocket` messes this up:

```
$ python -c 'from somelib import PyWidget, PySprocket
class BadWidget(PyWidget):
    pass
widget = BadWidget()
sprocket = PySprocket(widget)
widget.cycle = sprocket
del widget
del sprocket
'
PyWidget dealloc
Widget destruct
PySprocket dealloc with widget None
Widget::foo ��h�
```

Since there's a reference cycle, the garbage collector invokes the `tp_clear` to try to break the cycle.  Cython's `tp_clear` drops all references to Python objects.  Only after this happens does `PySprocket.__dealloc__` get to run.

Cython documentation [warns about `__dealloc__`](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/special_methods.html#finalization-method-dealloc) (although it took me a while to learn what conditions it was talking about, since it doesn't go into any detail).  So perhaps this approach is entirely invalid.

Can Cython support this use case?

As (what I hope is) a temporary work-around, I've moved to an approach that looks something like this:

```
cdef class PySprocket:
    cdef void *widget
    cdef Sprocket *thisptr

    def __init__(self, PyWidget widget):
        Py_INCREF(widget)
        self.widget = <void*>widget
        self.thisptr = new Sprocket(self.widget.thisptr)


    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
        Py_DECREF(<object>self.widget)
```

In other words, hiding the reference from Cython so that it is still valid in `__dealloc__`, and doing reference counting on it manually.

Comment: `string.h` and `stdio.h` are not valid C++ headers; the C++ equivalents are `<cstring>` and `<cstdio>`, and you really, really shouldn't be using them anyway. Why would you ever consider denying yourself the power of `std::string`, especially when performance is obviously not a concern (given that you're doing half the work in Python anyway)?

Comment: @Karl: they are valid in C++: D.5 of the standard.

Comment: @Steve legally but IMHO not morally ;)

Comment: The name field was a way to demonstrate there's a problem.  I was actually going for a segfault, but only managed to get some garbage data (on my system, at least).  I think the char* could be replaced with a std::string without substantively affecting the question.  Thanks for the reminder about header names, though.

Answer (score 6):

```
cdef extern from "somelib.h":
    cdef cppclass Widget:
        pass

    cdef cppclass Sprocket:
        Sprocket(Widget*)


cdef class PyWidget:
    cdef Widget *thisptr
    cdef set    sprockets

    def __init__(self):
        self.thisptr = new Widget()
        self.sprockets = set()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        print 'PyWidget dealloc'
        #PyWidget knows the sprockets and notifies them on destroy
        sprockets_to_dealloc = self.sprockets.copy()
        #with this solution spr items can call back to detach
        for spr in sprockets_to_dealloc:
          del spr
        del self.thisptr

    def attach(PySprocket spr):
        print 'PySprocket attach'
        self.sprockets.add(spr)

    def detach(PySprocket spr):
        print 'PySprocket detach'
        self.sprockets.remove(spr)

cdef class PySprocket:
    cdef PyWidget widget
    cdef Sprocket *thisptr

    def __init__(self, PyWidget widget):
        self.thisptr = new Sprocket(widget.thisptr)
        #You should be sure here that the widget exists
        widget.attach(self)
        self.widget = widget

    def __dealloc__(self):
        self.widget.detach(self)
        del self.thisptr
```

---

I come back a bit later to check what I have wrote, cause I'm quite tired,
but here is what matters: The point is that you
want to notify Sprockets when destroying Widget, and vice versa.

It is a general solution, can be tuned up.

You have to include error handling also, I have skipped that absolutely.
Nothing to do with garbage collector, there was a design problem in your code.

**EDIT:**
these codes are equialent:
A

```
class BadWidget(PyWidget):
    pass
widget = BadWidget()
sprocket = PySprocket(widget)
widget.cycle = sprocket ###1
del widget ###2
del sprocket
```

B

```
class BadWidget(PyWidget):
    pass
widget = BadWidget()
sprocket = PySprocket(widget)
sprocket.widget.cycle = sprocket ###1
del sprocket.widget ###2
del sprocket
```

`###2` will call `sprocket.widget.__deallocate__()` and it doesn't deallocates `sprocket.widget.cycle`, so the sprocket will survive the widget

Comment: I did not test it, but I have used both Python and C++ a lot, and checked the Cython documentation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion.  I tweaked your Cython a little to get it to compile (needed a forward PySprocket declaration, some `self` parameters were forgotten, and `del spr` isn't legal) - wish I could share the exact code but it won't fit in this comment box - and re-tried my simple test from the question, with this result: Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'" in <proposed.PySprocket object at 0xb756810c> ignored.  There is a similar error for 'copy' as well.

Comment: self.sprockets is an object of python set type, it is supported in cython. What self parameters were forgotten ? just mention 1-2 so I can edit my post, I didn't find them. Both of your codes run as expected, you see ? In your second code you inserted a del widget before del sprocket, that makes the difference.

Comment: Do you want a step-by-step explanation of what happens in your two case?

Comment: The PyWidget attach and detach methods are missing the self parameter.  A step-by-step explanation would be great; I think I already understand what's happening, but perhaps I overlooked something.

As regards the "del widget" preceding the "del sprocket" - the objects are in a cycle, so the order of the del should not matter.

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work.  The problem is that in `PySprocket.__dealloc__`, `self.widget` is not guaranteed to be valid and in `PyWidget.__dealloc__`, neither is `self.sprockets`.  Cython's tp_clear *may* have already set both attributes to None.  This will only happen when there is a reference cycle, since Python only calls tp_clear in that case.

Comment: Why don't you test in `PySprocket.__dealloc__` whether `self.widget` is `None` or not? Why should you make your code ugly using this comparison? Because: a sprocket can exist without a widget, and a widget can exist without a sprocket. They are independent. But why do you want to chain them together? You don't want to use a single sprocket in multiple widgets? If inside the sprocket you put only algorithm, and store all data inside the widgets, you don't have to bother with the deallocation sequence. Call every sprocket function through the widget. It isn't the strategy pattern? Or am I wrong?

Comment: The trouble with that is that the Sprocket destructor tries to use the Widget.  If the Widget is deallocated before the Sprocket, the Sprocket destructor crashes when it tries to use freed memory.  The Sprocket and Widget C++ classes belong to a library I'm wrapping, so I can't change their relationship or behavior.